# Elegant way to parse string containing boolean, ushort, hex, int, float to ushort?

Tags: c#

I have `Dictionary<string, string>` where the value can contain a hex, boolean, ushort, float or int. I have to parse those to either `bool` or `ushort` based on some property.

I'm getting the data from an json file, parsing it to an object with `Newtonsoft` if matters.

How can I achieve that elegantly without lot of `if's` with `TryParse()`?

I have some interface

```
interface SomeInterface {
    IEnumerable Data { get; set; }
}

class SomeClass : SomeInterface {
    public IDictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }

    IEnumerable SomeInferface.Data 
    {
       get => Data;
       set => Data = (IDictionary<string, string>)value;
    }
}
```

**example.json**

```
{
   "someproperty": "",
   "data": {
      "2938": "0x60" // can be "true", "3.14", "250"
   }
}
```

And this is parsed as usual

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<T>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Error = OnDeserializationError
        });
```

Where `T` in my case is `SomeClass`

Comment: Show us how you are “getting the data”. JSON does not represent bools or ushorts as strings, so if you are storing them as strings you are doing something wrong.

Comment: It is unclear what you actually want to achieve. Yes, you want to parse values of different types. The parsing itself is not the problem, actually. But how would you operate with those values of different types in your program? After all, you cannot just declare a variable of a particular type in your program and make it act like it is a different type on a whim. Thus, how would your program handle those values after parsing (just assume for a moment here that the values are already successfully parsed to values of the desired types) and which could be any of bool/ushort/int/float?

Comment: Is "23" a ushort, an integer, or a float?

Comment: edited. "23" in the json will be casted to ushort, no matter if "23" "23.4"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an elegant way, just think about all possible cases.

For boolean and hex

```
if(str.Length >= 2)
{
    switch(str[1])
    {
        case 'r'
            if(str == "true")
               //true
        case 'a'
            //false
        case 'x'
            //hex
    }
}
```

For other kind of numbers

```
var d = double.Parse(str);
var i = (int)d;

if(d != i)
    //float
else if (i >= 0 && i <= ushort.MaxValue)
    //ushort
else
    //int
```